# Does there exist a mapping on $S^2$ which is homotopic to indentity has only one fixed point?

Tags: algebraic-topology, spheres

It is well-known that if a mapping $f:S^2\to S^2$ is homotopic to identity, then it must have a fixed point. I am wondering that if there exists a map on $S^2$ which is homotopic to identity and has **exactly one** fixed point.

My attemptation:

I try to construct a vector field over $S^2$ which has a single zero. The flow $f_t$ generated by this vector is homotopic to $id$. However, I can't ensure that there exists some $t$, such that $f_t$ has only one fixed point and is exactly where the corresponding vector field vanishes .

Comment: @MoisheKohan I have edited the post and added my attemptation.

Comment: Do you know any theorems relating to existence of fixed points?

Comment: @TedShifrin I only know Lefschetz fixed-point theorem. But it can only tell us the existence, but not the number of fixed points.

Comment: Well, actually, that’s not true. If you know some differential topology and not just algebraic topology, the Lefschetz number of a smooth map is the sum of local Lefschetz numbers at the fixed points. See Guillemin & Pollack or Bott & Tu.

Comment: @TedShifrin I know that expression for Lefschetz number. However, there are more limitation for the map, such as smoothness and some kind of transversal. If we only consider continuous map, such expression will not hold.

Comment: It seems to me that the one point compactification of $(x,y)\rightarrow (x,y+1)$ will do.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Thank you, I think it is a good example.

Comment: @ConnorMalin do you want to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $n$ there exists a self map of $S^n$ which is homotopic to the identity and has exactly one fixed point. The map is obtained by starting with the homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ given by $(x_1,\dots,x_n) \rightarrow (x_1+1,\dots,x_n)$ and applying one point compactification. This evidently has a single fixed point, and it is homotopic to the identity because the original map $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is homotopic to the identity through homeomorphisms.

Comment: Do you mean a self map of $S^n$? (+1, obviously)

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thanks